# class decorator issue, or: How does Python discriminate methods from staticmethods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

### (I need a Python 3 internals guru, please)

I have a **class decorator** that modifies some functions but not others.
Simplified example:

```
import functools
import inspect
import types

def mydecorator(myobj):
    @functools.wraps(myobj)
    def decorated_method(*args, **kwargs):
        print("I'm decorated!")
        return myobj(*args, **kwargs)

    if inspect.isclass(myobj):  # act as class decorator
        for name, obj in myobj.__dict__.items():
            if name == "add":
                setattr(myobj, name, types.MethodType(mydecorator(obj), myobj))
        return myobj  # return decorated class
    elif inspect.isfunction(myobj):  # act as function decorator
        return decorated_method
    else:
        assert False, "can decorate only classes and functions"
```

So this will modify any `add` method to print "I'm decorated" before it runs.

We'll apply it to this class:

```
class MyClass:
    def add(self, x, y): return x + y
    def mul(self, x, y): return x * y
```

and it works alright. We do

```
#--- try out undecorated MyClass:
print("MyClass.add:", MyClass.add, "MyClass.mul:", MyClass.mul)
print("3+4 =", MyClass().add(3, 4), "3*4 =", MyClass().mul(3, 4), )

#--- decorate MyClass:
print("MyClass = mydecorator(MyClass)")
MyClass = mydecorator(MyClass)

#--- try out decorated MyClass in the same manner:
print("MyClass.add:", MyClass.add, "MyClass.mul:", MyClass.mul)
print("3+4 =", MyClass().add(3, 4), "3*4 =", MyClass().mul(3, 4), )
```

and get this output (from CPython 3.6.7 on Linux)

```
MyClass.add: <function MyClass.add at 0x7faededda0d0> MyClass.mul: <function MyClass.mul at 0x7faededda158>
3+4 = 7 3*4 = 12
MyClass = mydecorator(MyClass)
MyClass.add: <bound method MyClass.add of <class '__main__.MyClass'>>  MyClass.mul: <function MyClass.mul at 0x7faededda158>
I'm decorated!
3+4 = 7 3*4 = 12
```

So `mul` stays a plain function while the decorated `add` turns into a bound method. The decoration works correctly.

But when I now change the method such that `add` calls `mul` (ignore the fact this does not make much sense) as follows:

```
class MyClass:
    def add(self, x, y): z = self.mul(x, y); return x + y
    def mul(self, x, y): return x * y
```

the output turns into this:

```
MyClass.add: <function MyClass.add at 0x7fbc760870d0> MyClass.mul: <function MyClass.mul at 0x7fbc76087158>
3+4 = 7 3*4 = 12
MyClass = mydecorator(MyClass)
MyClass.add: <bound method MyClass.add of <class '__main__.MyClass'>> MyClass.mul: <function MyClass.mul at 0x7fbc76087158>
I'm decorated!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tryout.py", line 34, in <module>
    print("3+4 =", MyClass().add(3, 4), "3*4 =", MyClass().mul(3, 4), )
  File "tryout.py", line 16, in decorated_method
    return myobj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "tryout.py", line 7, in add
    def add(self, x, y): z = self.mul(x, y); return x + y  # round 2
TypeError: mul() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

It turns out that `mul` (although it is the same as before!) is now being called as if it were a `@staticmethod`: `self` is not passed.

I have plenty of questions:

1. Where does this astonishing effect come from?
2. What object is `add` bound to?
3. How does Python internally discriminate a normal method from a `@classmethod` or a `@staticmethod`?
4. What does `types.MethodType` really mean?
5. What would I write in its place to get a normal method, class method, or static method, respectively?
6. Where would I have found the documentation of all this?
7. Which of the answers pertain to Python properties as opposed to CPython implementation details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you should not replace the *function* `add` with a bound method. The way methods work is that a `function` object has a `__get__` method which, in the case of an instance method, returns a bound method for you to be called on the provided arguments. That is, given

```
class MyClass:
    def add(self, x, y): 
        return x + y
    def mul(self, x, y):
        return x * y

o = MyClass()
```

a call like `o.add(3,5)` is equivalent to `type(o).__dict__['add'].__get__(o, type(o))(3,5)`.

Your decorator should also simply return a new function, rather than a `method` object, and let its `__get__` method do its job.

Your new decorator, with some simplifications:

```
def mydecorator(myobj):
    @functools.wraps(myobj)
    def decorated_method(*args, **kwargs):
        print("I'm decorated!")
        return myobj(*args, **kwargs)

    # Decorating a function
    if inspect.isfunction(myobj):
        return decorated_method

    # Decorating a class
    if inspect.isclass(myobj):
        if "add" in myobj.__dict__:
            setattr(myobj, "add", mydecorator(obj))
            # Or just setattr(myobj, "add", decorated_method),
            # unless you think myobj.add might be a nested class
        return myobj

    # Anything else is type error.
    raise TypeError("can decorate only classes and functions")
```

---

Addressing some of your other questions...

> How does Python internally discriminate a normal method from a @classmethod or a @staticmethod?

The `classmethod` and `staticmethod` objects return objects that have different `__get__` methods than a regular `function` object.

> Where would I have found the documentation of all this?

The [Descriptor How-to Guide](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html) is a good place to start. It describes the descriptor protocol, as well as examples of how things like properties and methods make use of it.

Comment: Note this answers questions 1, 3, 6, and (implicitly) 5.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @chepner's great answer and to answer your point 4.

> What does types.MethodType really mean?

This special type allows us to add methods to already created instances, in your case there's no instance, hence when you pass `myobj` to it, you're basically setting `__self__` of the wrapper to its class rather than using its instance.

Let's take the simpler version of your class, without the decorator:

```
class MyClass:
    def add(self, x, y):
        z = self.mul(x, y);
        return x + y
    def mul(self, x, y): return x * y
```

Now:

```
>>> ins = MyClass()
>>> ins.add.__func__
<function MyClass.add at 0x7f483050cf28>
>>> ins.add.__self__
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f48304ef390>
```

As you can see, the `add` is a whole new object that has now info on which function to call and what to pass as first argument.

```
>>> ins.add(1, 2)
3
>>> ins.add.__func__(ins.add.__self__, 1, 2)
3
```

Now when we do, what you did:

```
>>> MyClass.add = types.MethodType(ins.add.__func__, MyClass)
```

This now passes the class to the function `add` instead of the instance:

```
>>> ins = MyClass()
>>> ins.add.__self__
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
```

which means the `self` inside `add` now is not the actual instance, but the class. Which means `self.mul` call there is equivalent to:

```
>>> MyClass.mul(1, 2)
...
TypeError: mul() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```